# Magento 2 : Running multiple websites in nginx

Tags: magento2, php, nginx

I am trying to run magento with marketplace site it supports only one base currency.

so we thought to create multiple websites inside magento admin .

```
 www.example.com/in/marketplace 
 www.example.com/gb/marketplace
 www.example.com/us/marketplace
```

> In configuration

```
{
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;

        include /var/www/nginx-sample.conf;

}
```

> nginx-sample.conf

```
root $MAGE_ROOT;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;

location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location /marketplace {
    try_files /marketplace/$1 /marketplace/$1/ /marketplace/index.php$is_args$args;
}
location /marketplace/pub/ {
    location ~ ^/marketplace/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/marketplace/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /marketplace/pub/static/ {

    location ~ ^/marketplace/pub/static/version {
        rewrite ^/marketplace/pub/static/(version[^/]+/)?(.*)$ /marketplace/pub/static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/marketplace/pub/static/?(.*)$ /marketplace/pub/static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/marketplace/pub/static/?(.*)$ /marketplace/pub/static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/marketplace/pub/static/?(.*)$ /marketplace/pub/static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /marketplace/pub/media/ {
    try_files $uri/marketplace/pub $uri/marketplace/pub/ /marketplace/pub/get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/marketplace/pub/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri/marketplace/pub $uri/marketplace/pub/ /marketplace/pub/get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri/marketplace/pub $uri/marketplace/pub/ /marketplace/pub/get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/marketplace/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|filemanager|adminer)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ ^/marketplace/pub/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your different websites running you need to set the corresponding variables `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` and `MAGE_RUN_CODE` as `fastcgi_param` anywhere where fastcgi is 
included in your nginx configuration and the Magento application is targeted.

So I think the following steps need to be done:

First you need identify the correct website code based on the request. If I understand your example correctly you are using the same domain for 3 websites with different url paths.
So the identification might go like this, please add the code somewhere in the top of your ngionx conf:

```
map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    ~/in/marketplace  website_code_for_in;
    ~/gb/marketplace  website_code_for_gb;
    ~/us/marketplace  website_code_for_us;
}
```

Second you need to add this two `fastcgi_param` directives into your fastcgi areas:

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
```

Anyway I'm not sure about the rest of your configuration. URLs are expected to begin with `/marketplace` so most likely you have to add in, gb or us in your `location` directives.
I guess you need to change `^/marketplace/` to `^/(in|gb|us)/marketplace/`.

I hope that helps and you get your configuration set up properly.

Comment: I am working on LEMP localhost, here is my main url : "http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/" & multi website url : "http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery" How can i use my url into Nginx setup? Shall i use magento2-dev.local instead of http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/ and magento2-demo.local instead of http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery @HelgeB thanks